# Debugging Intellij Idea Plugin in AppCode

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, appcode, app-code

How can I debug a plugin created in Intellij Idea using Gradle in AppCode? Every time when I'm running **runIde** Gradle task it starts Intellij Idea Community for debugging. My build.gradle file is:

```js
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.1'
}

group 'com.magicbytes'
version '1.0'

intellij {
    pluginName 'appcode'
    version '2018.1.2'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alternativeIdePath` property in the `intellij` block like this:

```
intellij {
      version 'IC-182.3458.5'
      alternativeIdePath='<full path to AppCode.app>'
}
```